# Visual Studio: Missing datetime picker

Tags: asp.net, datetimepicker

So I am trying to add a date time picker to my web application within Visual Studio, but it turns out I cant see it in the tool box. I am running VS 2012

If I go into the tool box and try and add it 'choose items > .net framework components > Find datetimepicker it is selected there!!!

Any reasons why I cant see it, or is there a way I can manually add this?

Comment: As far as I know, Visual Studio doesn't come with any date picker for asp.net. Can you be more specific? Which date picker were you expecting exactly?

Comment: Its ok I have used a Jquery date picker, I know a windows application comes with a datepicker but it seems ASP.NET web apps don't

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. Windows provides a datepicker, and .net provide a control based on that for windows applications. But there is no datepicker yet provided by HTML, although WebForms do provider a calendar that can be used to pick a date.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Date Picket in your web application,you can download Aajx Toolkit based on your framework version 3.5 or 4.0.

After downloading the Aajx Toolkit,unzip the folder and find the.dll file.

Now You have to add reference of it into your application.

Right click on your application tools and select add new tab and name it 'Ajax Tools'.

Right click on that tab and select 'Choose Items'.

Popup window will come and click on browse button,select that unzipped .dll file and click on 'Ok' button.

You can see reference is added into your bin folder and see the new Ajax controls under the new 'Ajax tools' tab.

you can find Calender Extender control over there and you can use it by simply drag and drop into your page.